# Rock Paper Scissors Game Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code for a simple Rock Paper Scissors game, but when I run it it just asks me for my input of Rock, Paper, or, Scissors, and then nothing else after that.  No alert after that all.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return alert("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "Rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Paper wins!");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "Scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Rock")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Schissors wins!");
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

By the way, I am using an online editor.

Comment: You might have problems with mixed cases. "Scissors" !== "scissors".

Comment: `var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice < 0.5) { 
    alert("Computer Wins!")
}`  :)

Comment: Duh!  Thanks showdev!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are mixing cases.  You set `computerChoice` to either `"rock"`, `"paper"`, or `"scissors"` but then inside of the function you are performing comparisons with `"Rock"`, `"Paper"`, or `"Scissors"`.

Just use lowercase throughout, and add `userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase()` after the `prompt()` call.

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8HCp/)

No `return`s needed.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        alert("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "Rock") {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
            alert("Rock wins!");
        } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
            alert("Paper wins!");
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "Scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "Rock") {
            alert("Rock wins!");
        } else if (choice2 === "Paper") {
            alert("Schissors wins!");
        }
    }
};

compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: The way the code is written, all inputs need to be consistently capitalized. This can be remedied using the `toLowerCase()` method from @F.J: http://jsfiddle.net/V8HCp/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will only display anything if `choice1` is an exact match with either `"Rock"` or `"Scissors"`.

You left out `"Paper"`. More significantly, you left out the possibility of spelling mistakes by the user.

You should have an 'everything else' branch. This will at least give you some feedback.

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return alert("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "Rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Scissors")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Paper wins!");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "Scissors")
    {
        if (choice2 === "Rock")
        {
            return alert("Rock wins!");
        }
        else if (choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return alert("Schissors wins!");
        }
    }
    alert('Unhandled combination! choice1 = ' + choice1 + ', choice2 = ' + choice2);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

String comparison in javascript is case sensitive:

```
"rock" != "Rock"
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious bug is that computer choices are all lowercase while `compare` function uses titlecase for Rock, Paper and Scissors.

I will also suggest some improvements to your code. First, `compare` function is doing two things now: calculating game result and signaling it to user. A better approach would be to do that separately. Function should do single thing:

```
function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    ...
        return "It's a tie";
    ...
        return "Rock wins";
    ...
}

alert(compare(...))
```

Second, lowercase user input. This will make it same format as computer choice and probably save you from user questions.

Third, check user input if it's one of available variants:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you ...?").toLowerCase();

var variants = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
if (variants.indexOf(userChoice) === -1) {
    alert("Don't cheat! Choose one of ...")
}
```

Forth, there are only six possible choice pairs in this game, so `compare` function should not be that long. One way to make it simpler is by explicitly listing all possible choice pairs:

```
var choicePairs = {
    'rock.rock': "It's a tie",
    'rock.paper': "Paper wins",
    'rock.scissors': "Rock wins",
    'paper.rock': "Paper wins",
    ...
}

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
    return choicePairs[choice1 + '.' + choice2];
}
```

And last you can reuse `variants` array to select computer choice:

```
var computerChoice = variants[Math.floor(Math.random() * variants.length))];
```

You can stash this select-random-element-from-array thing in separate function for clarity.

Have a good coding!